# how to edit a row in a table using javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <textarea id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">A</label>
            <input type="text" id="ans1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Answer">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">B</label>
            <input type="text" id="ans2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Answer">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">C</label>
            <input type="text" id="ans3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Answer">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">D</label>
            <input type="text" id="ans4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Answer">
        </div>
```

I have dynamically created a edit button. Now what I want is to change the values of the cell of a row by clicking on edit icon. I have added eventListener with edit icon also.

```
     function createIcon(className,fn,id) {
        var icon=document.createElement('i');
        icon.className=className;
        icon.setAttribute('qid', id);
        icon.addEventListener('click', fn);
        return icon;
      }

     function edit(){
        console.log("Edit Call ",this);
        var id=this.getAttribute('qid',id);
        document.querySelector('#name').innerHTML='value';

        }

    function printquestion () {
      td.appendChild(createIcon('fas fa-edit',edit,questionObject.id));
     // Where fas fa-edit is font-awesome edit icon class
          }
```

Comment: OK. But... what's the problem with your code?

Comment: you want to create a `function` which takes `row` as `parameter` and then change its item with something or add something to them. Am I Right?

Comment: We need to know the layout of the html

Comment: I have created my the edit function. Now what I want is when I click o my edit icon. on clicking he program control passes on to my edit function from there, it edits the cells of my row dynamically

Comment: edits them to what? more information is needed as to how the table is setup, and what you want it to change to, before anyone can help you

Comment: include examples of your table, both before, and after the edit so we know what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @FZs I m making an CRUD app for eg: online test. Here I whatever questions and answers adding to my table. I want to edit that data. Consider a situation where I;m entering an question in text field and I 've made a mistake and now I want to edit that question.

Comment: @tic I m making an CRUD app for eg: online test. Here I whatever questions and answers adding to my table. I want to edit that data. Consider a situation where I;m entering an question in text field and I 've made a mistake and now I want to edit that question.

Comment: And you're using no framework? Is this for the sake of learning? If it is for a real project, this should be done with a front-end framework like react or angular

Comment: @tic No i'm not using any framework because I was practicing javascript. This is just for learning javascript. It is not for real project. It's my personal project. Just for practice

Comment: @Maheer Ali,    I m making an CRUD app for eg: online test. Here I whatever questions and answers adding to my table. I want to edit that data. Consider a situation where I;m entering an question in text field and I 've made a mistake and now I want to edit that question.